# Google keeps randomly deleted passwords, why?

Tags: passwords

I used Google password manager and it KEEPS randomly deleting passwords.  Someone commented that its the clear cache section when you log out.  This has NOTHING to do with it.  One of the questions clearly says do you want to delete saved passwords, so obviously I did not check it to be cleared.  And not just any websites, websites that I use all the time.  Facebook, my bank, yahoo.  Why does Google Password manager keep doing it.  Who do I write to, to stop them from doing it?

Comment: Your issue isn't replicable. Probably you're missing out on some detail? Also, You mentioned "clear cache section when you log out." Do you keep logging in and out frequently?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is very clear and I didn't leave anything out.  Not sure you understood what I wrote.  I was stating about the clear cache of another writer, not me and said it doesn't apply to me......